# What is the best way to make an asynchronous request using React and without using jquery?

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, request

I'm trying to make an asynchronous request using React, but i don't want to use jQuery, so I'm looking for the best way to make this using React.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I create a function elsewhere in the class (or in an action if you are using a flux/redux implementation) that performs an AJAX request. There are several NPM packages that provide an easy to use API for AJAX. My personal favorite is superagent, but request is also good.